# SQL can't log in

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Hello my name is Ozan Bayrak

I have SQL on my pc and I have made a C# application.

I published the C# and installed another SQL server into this computer so I have 2 SQL

and now I can't Log in into my SQL cuz I get a error it says like this

"You can't run this Sql on 2005 and 2008"

who can help me please I really need to know this.

Everytime I want to log in it gives me a error.

when I go to services the SQLEXPRESS is offline too.

Thanks for the help

Ozan Bayrak

Comment: Please paste the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 28 - Server doesn't support requested protocol) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1).

this is the error message I get

Comment: and he's saying that I can't use Sql Server 2005 and 2008 on this version.

Comment: Are you running SQL 2005 Express Edition and SQL 2008 Express Edition on the same Server?  If you can not start one of the SQL Server instances from services, have you checked the Event Log to see what the real error message is?

Comment: What are you using to connect to the SQL Server are you using SSMS, if so, its possible the SSMS 2005 (SQL Server Management Studio) version or SSMS 2008 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have both, its possible that ports are conflicting thereby the SQLEXPRESS instance for MSSQL 2005 isnt starting up. Change the port number with the following steps

1. In **SQL Configuration Manager**, in the left side window under *SQL Server Network Configuration* select *Protocols for SQLEXPRESS*.
2. On the right side window, Right Click on TCP/IP and select Properties. In protocol tab, change *Enabled* to Yes
3. Under IP Address tab, search among IP1, IP2, IP3 and IP4 which has *Enabled* as Yes(if neither is enabled, just enabled one)
4. Which ever has *Enabled* as Yes, make sure *TCP Dynamic Ports* is blank and change the *TCP port* to anything other than 1433.
5. Also under IPAll, make *TCP Dynamic Ports* blank and for *TCP port* enter the same value that you entered above.
6. Click Apply and close the *TCP/IP Properties* window.

Now go back to **SQL Configuration Manager**, under *SQL Server Services*, right click on *SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)* and click Start.

Answer (score 1):

There's many possible issues here, including all or one of the below

1. **Test Open Port** The network on your LAN, can you ping SQL Server remotely on the default port 1433 on the specific IP Address (you can use PuTTY or Telnet to check this)
2. **SQL Configuration Manager** Check SQL Configuration Manager and see if the Network Protocol for SQL is enabled for TCP/IP, Named Pipes or Shared Memory
3. **Firewall and Default Port** Check the Windows Firewall make sure its allowing 1433.  Since you are testing, best thing to do is to disable the Firewall in Windows Services to confirm whether its a firewall issue or not.
4. **SQL Server Browser** SQL Server Instances (instances have the form SERVER\SQLEXPRESS or SERVERNAME\SQL1 for example).  Check in services and makes sure the "SQL Server Browser" is running.  Also, you must allow a Firewall rule for port 1434, which is the default port of the "SQL Server Browser".  This is necessary because the SQL Server maps and forwards the traffic based on the Instance Name, so this is the service that resolves the instance name.
5. **SQL Server Instance Port Varies** SQL Server Instances does not necessarily run on port 1433, in this case you will have to have the SQL Browser Running which maps the name to the port and directs traffic to the correct instance.  In your firewall, instead of allowing port 1433, you will have to allow sqlservr.exe Executeable Program.  The port also can be determined by looking at the SQL Server log File in the MSSQL\LOG folder in Program Files.  There will be an entry for "Server is listening on port ..."

My recommendation for you is to install SQL Server Express Management Studio (SSMS) which is the GUI interface to manage the SQL Server Express instance.  The link is below for both SQL Express and SQL Management Studio.  And see if you can connect to the servers that way first.  Another suggestion is for you to install both on a Local Computer and simply familarize yourself with SQL Server first before exposing it on the Network.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Turn on the SQLEXPRESS service and try to reconnect.

If the above fails, then read [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277).

In a nutshell, you will do the following:

- Enable remote connections on the instance of SQL Server that you
  want to connect to from a remote computer.
- Turn on the SQL Server
  Browser service.
- Configure the firewall to allow network traffic
  that is related to SQL Server and to the SQL Server Browser service.

Comment: I'm going to try this when I'm at home, Thanks for this solution I will let you know Thanks Sion_corn